# How to storeConfirmation in popup SeleniumIDE

Tags: javascript, firefox, automation, selenium-ide

Can u help me about **StoreConfirmation** for popup SeleniumIde ? + example command.
please answer only selenium IDE. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about default javascript alert or confirmation there are two commands for it:

**storeAlert**

> Returns:
>       The message of the most recent JavaScript alert
>
> Retrieves the message of a JavaScript alert generated during the
>   previous action, or fail if there were no alerts.
>
> Getting an alert has the same effect as manually clicking OK. If an
>   alert is generated but you do not consume it with getAlert, the next
>   Selenium action will fail.
>
> Under Selenium, JavaScript alerts will NOT pop up a visible alert
>   dialog.
>
> Selenium does NOT support JavaScript alerts that are generated in a
>   page's onload() event handler. In this case a visible dialog WILL be
>   generated and Selenium will hang until someone manually clicks OK.

**storeConfirmation**

> Returns:
>       the message of the most recent JavaScript confirmation dialog
>
> Retrieves the message of a JavaScript confirmation dialog generated
>   during the previous action.
>
> By default, the confirm function will return true, having the same
>   effect as manually clicking OK. This can be changed by prior execution
>   of the chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation command.
>
> If an confirmation is generated but you do not consume it with
>   getConfirmation, the next Selenium action will fail.
>
> NOTE: under Selenium, JavaScript confirmations will NOT pop up a
>   visible dialog.
>
> NOTE: Selenium does NOT support JavaScript confirmations that are
>   generated in a page's onload() event handler. In this case a visible
>   dialog WILL be generated and Selenium will hang until you manually
>   click OK.

You can see working example here : http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2013/10/selenium-ide-what-is-use-of.html

Hope it will help you.